# How to find the rank of students respective of their marks

Tags: python

I have an array of marks with N no of Entries. I have to find the rank of the student according to the marks i.e. if 2 students have same marks then they have same rank.

```
y=0
for x in marks:
 if marks[N] > marks[N+1]:
  rank=rank+1
 if marks[N] == marks[N+1]:
  rank=rank
  y=y+1
```

It is the logic i am trying to use in this but didn't get the required answer

For example :

```
marks = [89,88,79,74,74,74,74,74,64,56,56,25,24]
```

SO the rank should be like

```
score   rank
89      1
88      2
79      3
74      4
74      4
74      4
74      4
74      4
64      9
```

and so on .

Comment: Is your array sorted already? And could you please post your full code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: @Chinni        i have added my full code and yes the array is sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow. I've tried to answer in a way that mirrors the logic you described above. But looking at the code you supplied I would suggest reading up on some basic Python tutorials. Happy coding!

```
marks = [89,88,79,74,74,74,74,74,64,56,56,25,24]
current_rank = 0
global_rank = 0
current_mark = 0

for mark in marks:
    global_rank += 1
    if mark != current_mark:
        current_mark = mark
        current_rank = global_rank
    print(current_mark, current_rank)
```

Comment: but i want that if two students have same marks then they have the same rank but in this code the after 4th rank the student who got 64 marks gets the 5th rank which is wrong

Comment: can you help me

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I updated the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list `marks` is already sorted, you can pair adjacent marks by zipping the list with itself but with an offset of 1, and keep appending the same rank as the last rank if the adjacent marks are the same, or else append the length of the current ranks list plus 1:

```
ranks = [1]
for a, b in zip(marks, marks[1:]):
    ranks.append(ranks[-1] if a == b else len(ranks) + 1)
print(ranks)
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 10, 10, 12, 13]
```

Comment: its not running as expected

Comment: In what way is it not running as expected? See demo: https://repl.it/repls/OutgoingStaticProgramminglanguages

Comment: ooh sorry it seems like there is an issue in my compiler but it is also working.

Comment: Glad it is working for you. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Comment: Can you explain me what is ranks[-1] is doing

Comment: `ranks[-1]` refers to the last item of the list, so it is there to append the previous rank as the rank for the current item if an adjacent pair of items are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Students roll no to be auto generated

```
num = 1

def roll():
    global num
    num += 1
    return num
```

Comment: How will the same rank be given to multiple students if they have same marks?